# loading texture in SFML with std::future

Tags: c++, sfml, future

Visual Studio Express 2012, CTP1 c++ compiler

The following code works. It loads an image and displays it on the window until you close it.

```
#include <memory>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "hello");

    auto Load = []() -> std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> {
        std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> tex_ptr(new sf::Texture);
        tex_ptr->loadFromFile("hello.png");
        return tex_ptr;
    };    
    auto tex_ptr = Load();
    sf::Sprite spr(*tex_ptr);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event ev;
        while (window.pollEvent(ev))
        {
            if (ev.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }    
        window.clear();
        window.draw(spr);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

In the following code, I'm trying to load the image asyncronously using `std::async`.  It prints "load success", which indicates that the load succeeded in the lambda.  Then, outside, after I've retrieved the texture from the future, I check other properties of the texture.  The size prints out correctly.  However, no image shows up.  I just get a black window, which closes on command.

```
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "hello");

    auto Load = []() -> std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> {
        std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> tex_ptr(new sf::Texture);
        if (tex_ptr->loadFromFile("hello.png"))
            std::cout << "load success\n";
        else
            std::cout << "load failure\n";
        return tex_ptr;
    };

    auto tex_ptr_future = std::async(std::launch::async, Load);

    auto tex_ptr = tex_ptr_future.get();
    sf::Sprite spr(*tex_ptr);

    // Oddly, this prints out exactly what I expect
    auto size = tex_ptr->getSize();
    std::cout << size.x << 'x' << size.y << '\n';

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event ev;
        while (window.pollEvent(ev))
        {
            if (ev.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(spr); // nothin'
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Does anybody see anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That code works for me. Maybe it's because OpenGL can't really share state between threads and SFML uses OpenGL internally? The size field obviously doesn't need OpenGL to work.

Comment: @Pubby Of course! Only one OpenGL context could be assigned to a thread and an OpenGL context can only be assigned to a single thread. That means that you need to create a new OpenGL context for your loader's thread and share its resources with the main context.

Comment: @Pubby: Sounds reasonable.  So how does it work for you?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I don't know why it works for me, but I can confirm `Load` is being run in a separate thread. Maybe it's not using OGL for me?

Comment: @Pubby Maybe it's not running asynchronously (on the same thread). As for SFML not using OpenGL, not feasible.